# context data wont display anything in detailview

Tags: django

I'm trying to display this models' object where the user is as same as the detail view user. here is my views:

```
class ScientificInfoView(FormMixin, DetailView):
    model = ScientificInfo
    template_name = 'reg/scientific-info.html'
    form_class = ScientificInfoForm

    def get_success_url(self):
        messages.success(self.request, 'Profile details updated.')
        return reverse('scientific-info', kwargs={'pk': self.object.pk})

    def get_context_date(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ScientificInfoView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        #THIS IS THE LINE THAT WONT WORK#
        context['result'] = Results.objects.filter(user=self.object.user)
        context['sample'] = 'sample text sample text'
        #################################
        context['form'] = ScientificInfoForm()
        return context

    def post(self, request, pk):
        self.object = self.get_object()
        form = ScientificInfoForm(request.POST, instance=get_object_or_404(ScientificInfo, id=pk))
        if form.is_valid():
            return self.form_valid(form)
        else:
            return self.form_invalid(form)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        f = form.save(commit=False)
        f.user = self.object.user
        f.save()
        return super(ScientificInfoView, self).form_valid(form)
```

everything works fine except the result and sample data. it shows nothing in the template. It cant even render a simple text!

this is the templates:

```
{% for r in result %}
    {{r}}
{% endfor %} 
{{ sample }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a typo, the name is [get_context_data](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#adding-extra-context) and not `get_context_datE`.